# CMake how to set nasm file extenstions

Tags: c, assembly, cmake, nasm

I'm trying to compile nasm source files with `CMake` and have some misunderstanding about suffixes. By default `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS` has value `nasm;asm` so I wanted `*.S` to be recognized as `ASM_NASM` files by `CMake`. Setting

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS "${CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS};S")
```

does not seem to work. Here is the full `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(casm)
enable_language(ASM_NASM)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS "${CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS};S")
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILE_OPTIONS "${CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILE_OPTIONS} -f elf64 -g")
add_executable(min main.c min.S)
```

which prints the following error:

```
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: min
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "min".
```

While simply renaming the `min.S` to `min.asm` and replacing adding executable with

```
add_executable(min main.c min.asm)
```

works just fine:

```
Scanning dependencies of target min
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/min.dir/main.c.o
[ 66%] Building ASM_NASM object CMakeFiles/min.dir/min.asm.o
[100%] Linking C executable min
[100%] Built target min
```

I also tried to `set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS "")` without any effect so is user settings to the property simply ignored?

Comment: You don't tell CMake what the "main" language of your project is, so it can't really deduce how to link your executable program. Add a `LANGUAGES` clause to the [`project`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) command.

Comment: You're only enabling the `ASM_NASM` language, not the `C` language. You need to enable *all* languages you want to use.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude After some investigation I think that's a `ASM_NASM` bug anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, with the '.s' extension. This works fine:

```
set_source_files_properties(min.S PROPERTIES LANGUAGE ASM_NASM)
```

More general:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE src_asm "<path>/*.S" "<path>/*.s")
foreach(X IN ITEMS ${src_asm})
    set_source_files_properties(${X} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE ASM_NASM)
endforeach()
target_sources(target PRIVATE ${src_c} ${src_asm})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is sort of a bug. I use CMake 3.10.2 and I noticed that the variable is not being applied.

After running the `CMake` tool it produces output files in the build directory like

```
build_dir/CMakeFiles/3.10.2/
      |
      |__CMakeASM_NASMCompiler.cmake
      |
      |__CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
      |
      |
     ...
```

The `CMakeASM_NASMCompiler.cmake` looks as:

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER "/usr/bin/nasm")
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER_ARG1 "")
set(CMAKE_AR "/usr/bin/ar")
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER_AR "")
set(CMAKE_RANLIB "/usr/bin/ranlib")
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER_RANLIB "")
set(CMAKE_LINKER "/usr/bin/ld")
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER_LOADED 1)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER_ID "NASM")
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER_VERSION "")
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER_ENV_VAR "ASM_NASM")


set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS h;H;o;O;obj;OBJ;def;DEF;rc;RC)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_LINKER_PREFERENCE 0)
```

As can be seen the variable `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS` is not appeared in the file (even if it is set explicitly in the `CMakeLists.txt`).

After adding the entry

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS "asm;nasm;S")
```

into the file and regenerating `Makefile` the `.S`-files assembles just fine.